# Can i link a list of languages to radiobuttons?

Tags: c#, radio-button

I am designing a memory game where i need to use words from different languages instead of icons to play the game. In order to do so i need to select 2 languages from a choice of 3 sets. I have created 2 containers with 3 options in each, cancelling out the opposite option if one of them is checked. Now i want to link the list of languages i created to the radio buttons so that when the user selects the radio button, the list with the language is automatically generated. Can anyone help me please?

I have tried creating several if statements where i tried linking the lists to the radio button, but it is giving me an error

This is the code that i used to create the lists with the 3 languages.

> public frm_Edit_Language() {
>                  InitializeComponent();
>
> ```
>                  languages.Add(new Languages());//English
>                  languages.Add(new Languages());//Italian
>                  languages.Add(new Languages());//French
>
>                        languages[0].name = "English";
>                        languages[1].name = "Italian";
>                        languages[2].name = "French";
>
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Hello");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Bye");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Cat");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Good Morning");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Dog");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Summer");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Winter");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Car");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("How are you?");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Because");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Good night");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Thank you");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("My name is..");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("i live in..");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("boy");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("girl");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("pencil");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Man");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Woman");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("friend");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Good luck!");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Hot");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Cold");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("How old are you?");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("What is your name?");
>                           languages[0].Words.Add("Plane");
>
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Salve");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Ciao");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Gatto");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Buongiorno");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Cane");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Estate");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("l'inverno");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Macchina");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Come stai");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("perché");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("buona notte");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Grazie");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("mi chiamo..");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("abito a..");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("ragazzo");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("ragazza");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("matita");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Uomo");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("donna");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("amico");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Buona Fortuna");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Caldo");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Freddo");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Quanti hanni hai?");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("come ti chiami?");
>                           languages[1].Words.Add("Aereo");
>
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Bonjour");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("au revoir");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("chat");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Bonjour a tous");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Chien");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("été");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Hiver");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("voiture");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Comment vas-tu?");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("parce que");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("bonne nuit");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Merci beaucoup");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("je m'appelle");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("J'habite a");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Garcon");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("fille");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Crayon");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Homme");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Femme");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Ami");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Bonne chance");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Chaud");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("du froid");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Quel age avez-vous?");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Quel est votre nom?");
>                           languages[2].Words.Add("Avion"); }
> ```
>
> This is the code i tried running in order to link the list to the
>   radio buttons.
>
> private void btn_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>               {
>
> ```
>             if(rdo_english.Checked == true)
>             {
>                     language_picked = Convert.ToString(languages[0]);
>
>             }
>             if(rdo_italian.Checked == true)
>             {
>                     language_picked = Convert.ToString(languages[1]);
>             }
>             if(rdo_french.Checked == true)
>             {
>                     language_picked = Convert.ToString(languages[2]);
>             }
>             if(rdo_english2.Checked == true)
>             {
>                     language_picked = Convert.ToString(languages[0]);
>             }
>             if(rdo_italian2.Checked == true)
>             {
>                     language_picked = Convert.ToString(languages[1]);
>             }
>             if(rdo_french2.Checked == true)
>             {
>                     language_picked = Convert.ToString(languages[2]);
>             }
> ```

What i hoped for is that when the user clicks start game after checking the desired languages, the corresponding language is automatically binded with his/her choice.

Comment: Look into binding, you mention it in your post... Another alternative is set the tag property of the radiobuttons to the language.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ how would i be able to do that please? i'm new to coding so i',m not too sure on certain things

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i'll take a look at it, thank you !